# Acessibilidade - Mais de um CSS no site

Tags: jquery, css

Vou desenvolver um site de uma instituição para deficientes visuais. Muitos deles, irão acessar o site, e para cada usuário com problema específico, eu tenho um CSS diferente, que muda apenas as cores d fontes e de alguns elementos.

```js
$('#cor1Select').click(function() {
  $('link[href="styles.css"]').attr('href', 'cor2.css');
});
```

```css
.cor1 {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font: 400 14px/29px 'Montserrat', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff!important;
  background: rgb(0, 139, 206);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 139, 206, 1) 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 139, 206, 1) 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 139, 206, 1) 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#008bce', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
}

.cor2 {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font: 400 14px/29px 'Montserrat', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.cor3 {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font: 400 14px/29px 'Montserrat', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #f2e40a!important;
}

.cor4 {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font: 400 14px/29px 'Montserrat', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000!important;
}

.cor5 {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #063a91;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font: 400 14px/29px 'Montserrat', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff000!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="cor1Select" class="cor1" href="/"></div>
<div class="cor2" href="/">A</div>
<div class="cor3" href="/">A</div>
<div class="cor4" href="/">A</div>
<div class="cor5" href="/">A</div>
```

Cada **div** é um esquema diferente.
Fiz um teste com o **id**cor1Select, mas não está funcionando.
Como eu faço para chamar cada CSS?

Comment: Você quer ter vários arquivos css que terão classes unicas que definirão todas as classes que usará no site? E qual o problema de fazer exatamente isso? Crie quantos arquivos vc precisar, coloque todas as classes que precisar, e decida qual extensão de css vc precisará por algum evento em jquery. Por exemplo, ter uma classe `.primeira_cor div` num arquivo, e ter `.segunda_cor div` em um segundo arquivo, e assim por diante.

Comment: Exato. E como chamo com JQuery?

Comment: No clique de cada `a` invoque uma função, que no javascript mudará a class do body, por exemplo. Vou montar uma resposta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço um botão switch para alternar css?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189131/como-fa%c3%a7o-um-bot%c3%a3o-switch-para-alternar-css) (provavelmente tenhamos outras mais sobre o assunto)

Comment: Isso mesmo, a duplicata responde a pergunta adequadamente.

Comment: Mas ele vai incrementar o CSS que eu selecionar com o original. Ou eu tenho que duplicar tudo?

Comment: @GustavoCinque mudei a pergunta

Comment: voce pode fazer um form com inputs do tipo radio, e detectar o input selecionado, ai é só ficar 'escutando' o formulario, e ver se ocorreu mudança nos inputs, se mudar, altera o href do link da folha de estilos

Comment: @MatheusLopesMarques tem algum exemplo? Não entendi.

Answer (score 0):

o exemplo ai:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){

                $('input[name="input_selecionar"]').click(function(){

                    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+$(this).attr('id')+'.css">');

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="selecionar">
            <input type="radio" name="input_selecionar" id="1" value="1">
                <label for="1">primeiro</label>
            <input type="radio" name="input_selecionar" id="2" value="2">
                <label for="2">segundo</label>
            <input type="radio" name="input_selecionar" id="3" value="3">
                <label for="3">terceiro</label>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

OBS: só tá add mais tags  eu fiz apenas para mostrar rapidamente, voce deverá remover os outros  desnecessarios

Comment: caso tenha conseguido (ou nao) me fala que tento ajudar